# xhdpi scales images

Tags: android, layout, drawable

I need explanations.
I develop an application running for Honeycomb on a tablet 10.1.
I set an image 796x1228 pixel in drawable-xhdpi folder. When this image is called directly it displayed on 1/4 of screen size. If I set this image in a layout taking all screen width and height, it scales and result is not clean.
I search a long time before testing to put this same image in drawable-mdpi folder and get a good display.

The Android documentation says that for screen xhdpi we have to put our images in a folder xhdpi, but results is really bad.

Where is my trouble ? Thanks for your explanation, information...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 10.1" Honeycomb tablet is not xhdpi. It's an xlarge display, which is completely different. The XOOM for instance has an xlarge, mdpi display.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your device's screen is xhdpi? Usually, devices with big screens are something like `xlarge, mdpi or hdpi`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to show an image on a view you can put it into drawable-nodpi, load it and apply to your view (or let the app do it automatically).